# How to create new object names based on vector?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I'm trying to knit a document that creates ggplots and stores them as named objects, allowing me to print and discuss them at will throughout the document.

So far I've tried using this loop formula. It works great for my actual dataset, which has 120 variables. Today I want to look at some of them, tomorrow I may want to look at others. This lets me specify which ones I want.

```r
# Generate a data frame with 100 rows and four factor columns.
mydata <- data.frame(agegroup = as.factor(sample.int(10,100,replace = TRUE)),
                     incomegroup = as.factor(sample.int(10,100,replace = TRUE)),
                     othergroup = as.factor(sample.int(10,100,replace = TRUE)),
                     bygroup = as.factor(sample.int(3,100,replace=TRUE)))

# Choose the columns we're interested in
vars <- c("agegroup","incomegroup","othergroup")

# Make a list of names for the plots I want to create
plotnames <- c("ageplot","incomeplot","otherplot")

for (i in 1:3){

plotnames[i] <- ggplot(mydata, aes(bygroup, fill = mydata[,vars[i]])) + 
  geom_bar(position = "fill") + labs(title= vars[i], x="bygroup", y="") + 
  scale_fill_discrete(name= vars[i])


}
```

Obviously this doesn't work. I want R to summon a string from the plotnames list and use it as the name for a new object. How can I get this done?

EDIT: Changed plot to ggplot. This is what I'm really trying to do in my work. I tried to use base r to make the question shorter.

Comment: Base R graphics don't typically return something like this that you can store and recall (in fact, some R functions like `boxplot` return a named list of statistics and/or data); `ggplot2` *does* return something like that, but is not what you're using here.

Comment: `knitr` does caching of plots, is that what you're after? This allows you to (a) plot once, re-use whenever you re-render the rmarkdown document; and perhaps (though admittedly not confirmed) (b) re-include them later in the document.

Comment: You can try putting then in a named `list`. You could call the objects with `listname$plotname`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although you can, in principle, use `assign` to create object names in the way you describe, this is considered not good practice.  Better is to use `plotnames` as the names of list items.  Like this

```
plotlist = list()
for (i in 1:3){
    plotlist[[plotnames[i]]] <- ggplot(mydata, aes(bygroup, fill = mydata[,vars[i]])) + 
      geom_bar(position = "fill") + 
      labs(title= vars[i], x="bygroup", y="") + 
    scale_fill_discrete(name=vars[i])
}
```

Comment: Could you explain how to do the same with tables?

Comment: you can put any type of object into a list in exactly the same way.  Where it has `plotlist[[plotnames[i]]] <- ...` you can insert anything you want in the `...`